# What is the meaning of Brahmarakshasa?

Tags: asuras, rakshasa

What is the meaning of Brahmarakshasa and how is it different from Narasura, Rakshasa, Asura etc?

Is Ravana a Brahmarakshasa?

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer.

**When does one become a BrahmarAkshasa?**

> Samyogam patitaira gatvA parasya eva cha yoshitam |
>  Apahritya cha
>   viprasvam bhavati brahmarAkshasah || 
>  .....
>
> Manu Smriti 12.60. He who has associated with outcasts, he who has
>   approached the wives of other men, and he who has  stolen the property
>   of a Brahmana become Brahmarakshasas.

So, this is talking about afterlife.

Answer (score 2):

Brahm Rakshas is actually the
spirit of a Brahmin , a dead
scholar of high birth, who has
done evil things in his life or
has misused his knowledge, who
has to suffer as a Brahm Rakshas
after his or her death. The earth-
bound duties of such a scholar
would be to disperse or impart
knowledge to good students. If
he did not do so, he would turn
into a Brahma Rakshas after
death which is a very fierce
demonic spirit. The word
Brahm means Brahmin and
Rakshas , a demon. As per
ancient Hindu texts they are
powerful demon spirit , who have
lot of powers and only few in this
world can fight and over-come
them or give them salvation from
this form of life. It would still
retain its high level of learning.
But it would eat human
beings. They have the
knowledge of their past lives and
vedas and puranas . In other
words, they have qualities of
both Brahmin and Rakshas

> source:—https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmarakshasa

your another question about ravana ravana was a rakshasa .rakshasas were born to a great sage, Vishrava (or Vesamuni) and his
wife, the daitya princess Kaikesi so all children birn to kaikasi were rakshasas and Ilavida the another wife of sage vishwara was kubera.

> source:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana
>
> source:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubera